# How to add additional URL variables to a URL already rewritten with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

Does anyone have any idea if it is possible to put additional variables into a URL that you are using mod_rewrite to basically chop up into variables.

For example, if I have the URL:

```
website.com/post/53/post-title/
```

and I am using mod_rewrite to turn it into:

```
website.com/post.php?postid=53
```

Is there and elegant way to put additional variables into the "pre-rewritten" URL and keep them for my `post.php` script?

I.E., what if I create a link like the following:

```
website.com/post/53/post-title/?anothervar=6
```

So far it seems like my mod_rewrite code is just throwing out the additional variable and sending the URL to the `post.php` script like this:

```
website.com/post.php?postid=53
```

I do know that I can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the original URL in my php script (AKA `website.com/post/53/post-title/?anothervar=6`) before it gets rewritten by mod_rewrite and then just chop up the string to get that added on variable, but I just wanted to know if there was a more elegant solution that solely used mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can also use %{QUERY_STRING} to pass original query string to new url. or use it as you wish e.g.

```
RewriteRule /pages/(.*) /page.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [R]
```

Comment: Thanks, solved it.  What is that [R] at the end of your rewrite rule?  I don't have that at the end of any of my rewrite rule lines.

Comment: thanks, I'm adding this comment because I forgot to notify you in the one above it which read:  What is that [R] at the end of your rewrite rule? I don't have that at the end of any of my rewrite rule lines.

Answer (score 13):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

"qsappend|QSA"

Use, QSA to make mod_rewrite properly "merge" additional arguments when rewriting.

```
RewriteRule /pages/(.+) /page.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

That will add "page=$1" to whatever request the user made.

PS. Although take care, because mod_rewrite will happily overwrite "page" though if the user specifies it. No way around it that I know off.

Comment: [QSA] solved it for me. I have a page (example.com/page) that gets translated to spanish if you visit the spanish link for it (example.com/spanish/pagina) which is rewritten to example.com/page?language=spanish. I was trying to append an additional GET variable to /spanish/pagina which was to be sent via ajax and kept getting the HTML web page back (the ajax calls for the same page but only executes a php script to send json data instead of generating the html content). Anyone doing something like this should be wary of using QSA now